# Set different warning thresholds for Nagios on weekends

Tags: monitoring, nagios, cpu-usage

I'm using Nagios to monitor CPU usage on my servers with the `check_load` plugin.

On weekends we have some batch jobs running and there are hardly any real users anyway, so I'd like to have the warning threshold a little higher.

I have seen solutions to completely disable notifications during these times, but I'd like to still get notifications if the load gets really high.

I've also see solutions to defince 2 services, one for weekday and one for weekends, but I'd like to keep the CPU load in a single chart for the whole week.

Any ideas or examples how I can have different thresholds in a single service ?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this depends on where your thresholds are defined. If they're defined on the host being checked, e.g., hard-coded in nrpe.cfg, then you need to keep two copies of nrpe.cfg and rotate them on a schedule. (And restart NRPE every time it swaps.) This can be done with a cron job and a simple bash script.

If you have NRPE accepting args, and are passing the thresholds in as ARG1, ARG2, etc., from the Nagios end, you have a few options.

You can define two nearly-identical services, with different/non-overlapping check periods and different thresholds passed as args.

Or you can use one service, and dynamically change the threshold arguments. It's complicated, but it can be done. It's called [Adaptive Monitoring](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/adaptive.html).

The basic idea is to submit external commands on a schedule to change object settings. In your case, you'd want to change the check_command to pass in different thresholds. Something like... change `check_nrpe!check_load!5 10` to `check_nrpe!check_load!15 30` or similar.

For adaptive monitoring, what you're looking for is the external commands that start with "CHANGE" in the [command list](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandlist.php), specifically [CHANGE_SVC_CHECK_COMMAND](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandinfo.php?command_id=108) in this case.

Comment: Replacing the command incl. parameters would do. Is there an example config somewhere ? The documentation says that the feature won't be useful for 99% of the users...

Comment: Adaptive monitoring is an "advanced" topic, which is why the docs say 99% of people won't need it. Edited answer to include more info, if you really want to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this in the past and it appears there is no built-in solution (I might be wrong though!).

What I ended up doing is creating two different configuration files for the service, I then added a cron job that would run each Friday and Sunday night to swap the two files and reload nagios (service nagios reload).

The swapping can for example be done by renaming *cfg* file that should not be used, since nagios will only read files ending with *.cfg*

A more elegant solution would be to just change the value of the file using *sed*